# Check Console -- error of computer or program?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, console

The code is able to compile and run but instead of printing at the end I receive a pop up error message (error below) but I don't understand what it means or why I am getting it.

```
public class Employee10
{   
public static void main ( String args[] )
{
    Employee e1 = new Employee();
    Employee[] arr = new Employee[2];

    int j = 0;

    for ( int i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        arr[0] = e1;

        String nameF = Input.getString("Please enter a First Name");
        String nameL = Input.getString("Please enter a Last Name");
        int Number = Input.getInt("Please enter an Employee Number");
        String Street = Input.getString("Please enter a Street address");
        String City = Input.getString("Please enter a City");
        String State = Input.getString("Please enter a State");
        double Zip = Input.getDouble("Please enter a Zip Code"); 
        int Month = Input.getInt("Please enter a Month");
        int Day = Input.getInt("Please enter a Day");
        int Year = Input.getInt("Please enter a Year");

        e1.setNumber(Number);
        e1.setName( new Name(nameF, nameL));
        e1.setAddress(new Address(Street, City, State, Zip));
        e1.setHireDate(new Date(Month, Day, Year));

        System.out.println(e1.getEmployeeString());


        arr[i] = e1;

    }   

    for ( j=0; j < arr.length; j++ )
    {
        System.out.println( arr[j].getEmployeeString() );
    }   
    }
}
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

> The Java class file "Employee10.class" could not be launched. Check
>   the Console for possible error messages.

What does all of this mean? Where is the Console I can check?

I am using a fully updated Mac and am using the Terminal application to run my code.  Is this the console?

Comment: can you tell us what do you do to run ir what steps did you take ??

Comment: "Could not be launched" has nothing to do with the content of the program, except for any `package` declarations. It is about how you attempted to run it, so include maximum detail on what you typed where.

Comment: @StackFlowed  I finished writing my program, then opened the terminal application, navigated to the folder where the program and corresponding classes were then typed "javac Employee10.java" to compile the program.  It compiled successfully but when I went to run it it got half way through then I got the above mentioned error message.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Above is a description of what I did with the program.

Comment: How many times are you going to post same problem again and again? I'd flag that post as a duplicate, but I've hit the today's limit, here are your previous questions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276009/error-message-int-cannt-be-converted-to-type
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34320509/post-compile-error-check-console

Comment: @mkierc  I posted the same program because I was experiencing different errors each time so I thought changing the post to specify the new errors would help me get more targeted responses.

Comment: Every one of your posts contains `The Java class file "Employee10.class" could not be launched. Check the Console for possible error messages.` error.

Comment: I flagged both "newer" questions as a duplicate of the first one, since code and error message are the same.

Comment: *I was experiencing different errors each time* - The content of your posts have been exactly the same each time, to the point where even the edits I made were the same fixes someone else did on another question. The only thing you've changed is the title of your posts.

Comment: @BSMP  Given that I am new and inexperienced with coding and the coding world I didn't know that I was able to reply to peoples comments so when I implemented changes but still received the same error message I couldn't reach back out to those people so I reposted the errors.  Each time I reposted the error message was the same but the location of it was different causing confusion for me.

Comment: You knew you could post comments on answers, you did that on the first question. What made you think you couldn't respond to comments on your question? Also, when people are leaving comments that your question is missing info, you should [edit] that info into your question anyway instead of putting it into a comment. Spend some time in the [help] on how to use the site.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    ...
}
```

try

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
}
```

In Java, as I have found out, not only is it good practice to declare an array in this format `String[] exe` instead of `String exe[]`, but also that it usually also runs better in that format, as it is harder to get variable types mixed up. Also, your program runs without a hitch on my computer when you do `String[] args`.

I'm assuming you have used a language like C before?
Here's a link to the syntax of a main method in Java: [Java Main Method](https://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/KarelJava2ed/ch2/javamain.html/).
Hear's a link to the syntax of an array in Java: [Java Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Hope that helps.

Comment: This will only solve OPs problem when he uses a very broken compiler and a broken JVM and this is very unlikely. So you should write this _advice_ in a comment, not as an _answer_.

Comment: @Tom What do you mean by a broken compiler and a broken JVM?

Comment: `String args[]` is not invalid, so it will only cause trouble for OP if he uses a broken compiler (or JVM) which thinks it is invalid. It is the proper style to write `String[] args`, yes, but such advices belong into the comments, since they won't solve OPs problem.

Comment: @Tom I am the OP.  The problem is after I enter everything, nothing gets printed.  That would be a RunTime Error correct?  I have tried switching my console from Terminal to BlueJ to no avail.  Is there a better console out there or is the program not correct?

Comment: @COB1999 "I am the OP" right, I missed that. Every console should be able to do what you want it to do. If it does something else, then the problem is most likely in your program. When you get the info *"Check the Console for possible error messages."*, then check how you run your program and read the help page about displaying the console. If  you use BlueJ, then there should be a button in the menu to display it.